# REST + user profile

Tags: rest, profiling

I'm using swagger for modelling a REST service. At the moment, I'm using the api_key authorization with a token in the header. Something like:

```
securityDefinitions:
  UserSecurity:
   type: apiKey
   name: Authorization
   in: header  
...
path:
 /cars:
   x-swagger-router-controller: cars
   get:
    security:
      - UserSecurity: []
```

Let us suppose that I have a */cars* controller and different user types

- TypeA: cars only with red or yellow color
- TypeB: cars only with yellow or green color
- TypeC: cars only with blue or white color
- and so on...

Lets us suppose that I have two users:

- UserA: enabled for TypeA and TypeC
- UserB: enabled for TypeB

I know that my REST server should not save any session data, but I do not understand how to manage this requirement.

What is the best practice ?

Riccardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution

I'm going to implement a Json Web Token and passing the profile in the token

R